# fast/easy file system snapshot

Tags: filesystem, workspaces, snapshot

I am working in a lot of team projects and usually team members come to my computer in an attempt to help and they ruin my workspace. My workspace for a project spans folders in different locations.
Is there an easy/fast file system snapshot application/script? When I say easy/fast I mean that I do not have to go through complicated configs or hundreds of pages of manuals.

Comment: A solution can also be (and would also be preferred) a directory versioning tool, but I cannot use any traditional tool and I do not want to manually checkpoint everything. I would want something like: save context, leave coworker to do his job, go back to my context.